# groovy-maven-plugin: How to add a dependency for executing groovy scripts?

Tags: maven, groovy, gmavenplus

I want to execute a small groovy script via the groovy-maven-plugin(or gmavenplus) during build, I need a third-party dependency, but the project itself doesn't need this dependency, how to add this dependency only for executing groovy scriptes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the needed library as a [plugin dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag).

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            ....
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```